# Connect to multiple servers at the same time using sockets in NSStream

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nsstream

I am creating a socket based iOS app using Objective-C, now my requirement is to connect to two servers at the same time.

I am using `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` and I am able to connect to the first server as well as send and receive data with the server using the delegate method.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
```

How do I have connect with a second server at the same time or multiple servers at the same time?

Comment: Formatted everything properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, what you will typically do is create multiple instances of the class where you implemented the

`- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent`

For instance you could have your own `CustomConnection` class with an `init` method like this:

`- (id)initWithUrl:(NSURL *)url`

But what you could also do (if you want to keep everything in one place) just test for the NSStream that is sending you the event:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
   if(theStream == self.serverAInputStream)
   {
      //input from server a
   }
   if(theStream == self.serverBInputStream)
   // ... and so on!
}
```